# I would like to cut an image into several sections

Tags: inkscape, gimp, interface-design, crop, template-design

**HI Graphic Design friends**,
I'm in trouble...
My question for you are these:

- **Can I create a GIMP/Inkscape template that** once opened and inserted a photo **crop exactly the same point in the same size?**
- If I can't create similar templates, **can I make macros**? If yes, how can I do?

---

#### The problem Sample:

Imagine having many similar images and having to crop the red boxes for each one

| [image: Normal] | [image: i would cut this] |
| --- | --- |

How can I be *accurate and fast?*
*Thanks for the helps.*

Comment: I am sure [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) can be used to crop multiple files at the same location. You have to work yourself through its command line options, of course.

Comment: actually I tested it as software but not having people to help me understand it, it is difficult for me to understand.
Could you suggest me where to find a good manual from A to Z?

Comment: [How to crop an image using ImageMagick from the command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/1161340/how-to-crop-an-image-using-imagemagick-from-the-command-line)

Comment: thanks a lot, I owe you

Comment: [For Unix/Linux: How do I run a command on multiple files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80851/how-do-i-run-a-command-on-multiple-files)

Comment: [For Windows: windows/cmd running exe on multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34616216/windows-cmd-running-exe-on-multiple-files)

Comment: this is what I was searching for

Comment: [Batch Crop Images With Imagemagick](https://deparkes.co.uk/2015/04/30/batch-crop-images-with-imagemagick/)

Comment: maybe you can put an answer with these links so I mark the answer as correct... thanks

Comment: Link-only answers are frowned upon in the SE network. I am fine if you accept @BillyKerr's answer, which is a response to your literal question. Better take my comments above as a suggestion to work on your "Google foo" ;-)

Comment: ok, thanks for helps, I finally succeeded thanks to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @DocBrown I'm  finally succeeded to what I was looking for:
Making macros that cut Images in several section, many time, the same size.

### How to use the Crop in Imagemagick

Using ImageMagick for windows I found the right idea using this website
[Batch Crop Images With Imagemagick](https://deparkes.co.uk/2015/04/30/batch-crop-images-with-imagemagick/)

### How I make the Batch File

Using an Italian PDF that talks about [Batch files](https://areeweb.polito.it/didattica/fondinf/Piccolo/lucidi/dos/esempi_batch.pdf) I wrote a clear code that answers my request, and I would like to let you know because it could be *useful to everyone*:

```
    ECHO OFF   
    CLS 
    ECHO File To CUT ScreenShots png
    :: Clear The Directory cropped where I will put the imgs 
    RD /Q /S C:\Users\alessandro.golin\Desktop\CroPpED
    MD C:\Users\alessandro.golin\Desktop\CroPpED
    
    :: Starting crop 
    :: The Input file is called C_ToCrop.png 

    ECHO ---- FIXTURE Casambi Section----
     : Magick convert -crop [size (see the link)] [input.png] [output.png]
     magick convert -crop 579x99+30+199 C_ToCrop.png C_Fixture.png

     :: Displace the file cropped in the cropped directory, then delete the file on desktop
     COPY C:\Users\alessandro.golin\Desktop\C_Fixture.png C:\Users\alessandro.golin\Desktop\CroPpED
     DEL C:\Users\alessandro.golin\Desktop\C_Fixture.png

     :: Closing message
    ECHO ---- FIXTURE Casambi Displaced in CroPpED Directory ----
    
    ECHO ---- TEST Casambi Section----
     magick convert -crop 579x100+30+498 C_ToCrop.png C_Test.png
     COPY C:\Users\alessandro.golin\Desktop\C_Test.png C:\Users\alessandro.golin\Desktop\CroPpED
     DEL C:\Users\alessandro.golin\Desktop\C_Test.png
    ECHO ---- TEST Casambi Displaced in CroPpED Directory ----
    
    ECHO ---- UNIT Casambi Section----
     magick convert -crop 579x127+30+797 C_ToCrop.png C_Unit.png
     COPY C:\Users\alessandro.golin\Desktop\C_Unit.png C:\Users\alessandro.golin\Desktop\CroPpED
     DEL C:\Users\alessandro.golin\Desktop\C_Unit.png
    ECHO ---- UNIT Casambi Displaced in CroPpED Directory ----
    
    PAUSE
```

Thank you very much everyone for the **helps** and the efforts you have made to help me✨

Answer (score 4):

No to both of your questions.

Inkscape can't edit/crop raster images at all. It's a vector image editor, so it's no use for what you want.

GIMP has no template functionality as such, other than regular XCF (GIMP document) files, but these can't "do" anything.

GIMP has no macro recording capabilities, although it can be scripted using ScriptFu or Python for automation. I've no idea how to script GIMP unfortunately.

It's possible to semi-automatically slice an image using Guides in GIMP.  Although it will produce extra slices you will have to discard.

Example

[image]

Comment: This is a smart idea.. thanks

Comment: you said GIMP has no template functionality, well that's quite right, I worked around it and found a solution: save the page with guides and use it for different images, not a real template but it's similar... Really thanks for it

Comment: I leave you the answer marked as accepted because you have provided for first a very good and elegant answer; thanks for the helps you give to me every time

Comment: @Lale - thanks, but do you know you can actually accept your own answer as best?  Since you eventually went with a different method, it might be better to select that as best.

Answer (score 2):

In Gimp you can record settings for most tools and the Crop tool is not exception.

[image]

On one image, set the crop tool to you liking (size & position), and click the "Save" icon (leftmost), and give a name to your settings.

Later on, start the crop tool, click on the image, then click the "Restore" icon (2nd from left) to restore the settings, and strike [Enter] to apply the crop.

If you want to do this to many images, it is worth investigating using ImageMagick in a shell script.

It is also possible to make a Gimp script (and assign a shortcut to your script...), but this is better asked on StackOverflow.

Comment: maybe I should ask since I've never write a Gimp script.. thanks for the idea

Answer (score 1):

This is actually super easy in Inkscape.

Select the image, then go to Object > Pattern > Object to Pattern.
Next, draw your sections on top.
Combine them.
Select both, the image-pattern-rectangle and the cut lines.
Path > Division.

Comment: yes, thanks for the good idea, but what I wanted to do was **create a template**, so every image I had to cut, I could automatically insert it into the template and cut without too many steps ...

Comment: That's possible, too, if all images have the same size. Check https://gitlab.com/Moini/nextgenerator, or just exchange the image under the clip manually. You could do this more comfortably by using a clone and a group. But yes, I would also use imagemagick for cropping a bunch of raster images :)

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, I looked at the link you give me, well next time I will check it, thanks; The problem is I'm lazy `:)` so if I only just have to on double click an `.exe`, I much prefer it✨... also because I have upgraded the batch and now it moves the files I cut directly to the correct destination folders.   
Automation is the wonder of computers